# Weird Vite error: [vite] Internal server error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: vite

Why does vite give me this error?

```
[vite] Internal server error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

What does it mean?  I just started getting it all of a sudden, and there is no more information about what could be causing it.

Answer (score 3):

This error happened because I did a GET request from the client to a nonexistent URL on my computer.  I am using vite's proxy server option in my vite.config.js so all requests to the `/api/*` endpoint get proxied to my local server.  I accidentally did a request to `/users/me` instead of to `/api/users/me`.  I believe vite was trying to load the `/users/me` directory on my computer, which it doesn't have access too, and thus the error.  All I had to do was properly add the API prefix which I had forgotten, and it worked out correctly.